# bootstrap tab selection to determine ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this function in javascript, which looks like this:

```
function getlivefeed() 
{       
    var msglist = document.getElementById("updates");
    var type = msglist.getAttribute("data-id-type");        

    var response = $.ajax({ type: "GET",   url: "iterations/live.php?type=" + type + "&token=" + Math.random(),   async: false }).responseText;     
    if (response != "undefined")
        document.getElementById("updates").innerHTML = response;                                        
}
```

As you can see this function looks at the a div data attribute and reads the value and uses that in the ajax call.

I want to be able to change this attribute somehow, when i change the index of my tab.

the tab is a bootstrap tab control.

the markup for the tab is:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#atlass" data-toggle="tab">Atlass</a></li>
  <li><a href="#avi" data-toggle="tab">Aviation</a></li>
  <li><a href="#proc" data-toggle="tab">Processing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#it" data-toggle="tab">IT&S</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="atlass"><div id="updates" data-id-type="1"><div class="alert alert-default well" style="background-color: #f1f1f1"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Portal is Initilizing... Please Wait.</div></div></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="avi"><div class="well" style="background-color: lightsteelblue;">Aviation Feed Will go here.</div></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="proc"><div class="well" style="background-color: lightsteelblue;">Processing Feed Will go here.</div></div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="it"><div class="well" style="background-color: lightsteelblue;">IT&S Feed will go here.</div></div>
</div>
```

Overall,  my question is this, how can i make my function work with a different 'type' `iterations/live.php?type=1 or type = 2 or type = 3` ect when i change the index of my tab?

much help appreciated!

Comment: `async:false` no!!!!!

Comment: what? how does this help me

Comment: Perhaps Arun means: "Try switching `async` to `true`"?

Comment: there isn't a problem with my function if you read the question properly.

Comment: @Dean mine was not an answer.... it was just pointing to the fact that you should not use `async:false`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I've understood your question, you want to change the value of data attribute right?

You can use jQuery's data function to change data attribute..

```
$("#atlass").data("id-type",2);
```

To trigger a script when tab is switched :

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous tab
 // your logic here...
})
```

What this code actually does : 
The tab links are bound. Whenever user clicks on tab element, this script fires..

Comment: this is correct thanks, but how do i trigger this depending on the type of tab i am on?

Comment: There are various tab events for bootstrap. I will explain that in above answer... :-)